# Azure maps cluster position discrepancies

Tags: javascript, azure-maps

I've got a list of positions that I retrieve from an ms endpoint like so:
https://atlas.microsoft.com/search/fuzzy/json?top=100&typeahead=true&subscription-key=subscription-key&api-version=1&query=Leeds
The user then selects one of the proposed addresses and the position provided by this endpoint is then used to be displayed on a map that uses clusters. So for Leeds for example, I have the following:
-1.548567, 53.801277

However, when I create the clusters in the `clusterRenderCallback` function I provide upon creating the `HtmlMarkerLayer`, I get positions that are close to the ones I've provided, **but different** and I have no idea how or why.

so the code would look something like:
First I create the dataSource

```js
dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource(null, {
  //Tell the data source to cluster point data.
  cluster: true
});
map.sources.add(dataSource);
```

Then I manage the cluster creation inside the `HtmlMarkerLayer` creation:

```js
clusterRenderCallback: function (id, position, properties) {
  var cluster = new atlas.HtmlMarker({
    position: position, // different position to that which I have provided
    htmlContent: `<div>${properties.point_count_abbreviated}</div>`,
    values: properties,
  });

  map.events.add('click', cluster, clusterClicked);

  return cluster;
}
```

And here I create points to add to my data source:

```js
let features = list.map(x => new atlas.data.Feature(new atlas.data.Point(new atlas.data.Position(x.lon, x.lat)), x));
dataSource.add(features);
```

**The position I receive for the Leeds cluster for example is -1.549072265625, 53.80065082633024, even though I had 2 poisitions in Leeds, both made out of the same coordinates: -1.548567, 53.801277**
It seems like there's some sort of mechanism inside the atlas code that "fixes" the provided coordinates; anyone knows how to stop this or what am I doing wrong here?

==EDIT 02/05==

ok, so following @rbrundritt answer, here the last bit of code I should have added, showing what we do once the cluster is clicked:

```js
function clusterClicked(e) {
  var cluster = e.target;

  datasource.getClusterExpansionZoom(cluster.properties.cluster_id).then(function (zoom) {

    map.setCamera({
      center: cluster.getOptions().position,
      zoom: zoom
    });
  });

}
```

And this is where we have our problem with this discrepancy- clicking on the cluster zooms in to the zoom level where the cluster breaks; however, since we centre the map to the cluster position, **the pin position, being different to the cluster one, is not being seen in the map on that zoom level** (ie 3 afair). On top of that we have no way of knowing inside the context of this function to what pin does the cluster corresponds, this leaves us with a buggy behaviour.

Comment: The issue isn't clear. The cluster position will rare ever be the same as the position of any of the pins you pass into your data source. Trying to understand what your issue is, I think you mean that when the map zooms in, some of the pins that were in the cluster are no visible on the map. I suspect the issue is that the positions of the pins are within the map view, but the icons aren't since the pixel size of those are not taken into consideration. A couple of options. Try passing zoom through Math.floor to round down. Try passing in a padding option when setting the map camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I wasn't aware of what the `datasource.getClusterLeaves` method was returning (I've simply mistaken the leaves for the verb leaving). This is what I was looking for, so my code now looks like this:

```js
function inSamePosition(pos1, pos2) {
  return pos1.data.geometry.coordinates[0] == pos2.data.geometry.coordinates[0] 
    && pos1.data.geometry.coordinates[1] == pos2.data.geometry.coordinates[1];
}

function clusterClicked(e) {
  var cluster = e.target;
  (cluster.properties.cluster_id, Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, 0).then(pins => {
    let position = pins.every(p => inSamePosition(p, pins[0])) ? pins[0]['data'].geometry.coordinates : null;
    datasource.getClusterExpansionZoom(cluster.properties.cluster_id).then(function (zoom) {
      map.setCamera({
        center: position ? position : cluster.getOptions().position,
        zoom: zoom
      });
    });
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Clusters should rarely have the same coordinates as any points that they contain. Clusters group overlapping points together and an average position is used to represent that group on the map. When a cluster breaks apart into its individual points then that marker will have the original position value.

Comment: 'should' is the key word here; unfortunately, you may have to show a map with many results, some with "real" clusters (as you've described), some containing multiple results in the same address. Airbnb may have multiple apartments in the same address; one company may have multiple job offers...

Comment: Still, thanks for taking the time to answer. I appreciate it :)

Comment: There are a lot of different ways to handle the scenarios you mentioned. One method is to change the max cluster zoom setting so that all pins appear, unclustered at certain zoom levels. Another option for when multiple results at the same location is to use the spider cluster visual: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/index.html?sample=Expanding%20Spider%20Clusters or to have a popup where the user can flip through the results.

Comment: Yeah- this is exactly what we do, we uncluster on zoom level 3 (I believe) and upon clicking on the cluster we move down to that zoom level & centre the map to the cluster position, however this hides the original pin position. See added edit to my original question text.

Comment: oh, yeah- and once the user sees the original pin, they simply click it and get a popup where they can move from one 'result' to another.